# Test ethernet port for data loss

Tags: ethernet, testing, packetloss

We are trying to test the ethernet phy on our linux box for data loss.

As of now we just establish a tftp connection to a server to upload and download a file. Whenever a mismatch occurs, it is reported as failure.
This is not a very nice test, as any mismatch might have been caused by the network itself and not a phy problem.

Can you suggest a way to test the ethernet phy in a better way for data loss?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have `ethtool` installed (Linux)

Comment: Check the interfaces on both sides (linux box and switch to which it is connected) for errors and discards. A test on application level as you do them can't hurt as its results encompass all lower layer errors. However, without monitoring at the lower layers, troubleshooting might become difficult in case something is not working.

Comment: @Kwaio I don't have ethtool as of now.

Answer (score 0):

- run `iperf` on the interface in question as either client or server, and run the opposite on a different machine. Let it run for whatever time you wish to test.
- now look at the output of `ip -s link show dev ethX` on both machines, where `ethX` is the name of the interface